# How to always show top-menu instead of showing on-hover?

Tags: 14.04, menu

Currently Ubuntu terminal shows the folder path on the top-bar
I need to hover over the top of screen to show the menu as shown in screenshot

[image]

How do I always show that menu always so I dont need to hover first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install dconf-editor if not yet installed.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Open `dconf-editor`, search for "always-show-menus" and activate the setting by checking the box.
Note that activating this will always-show-menus for all applications.

[image]